# Make default value on textbox triggered when other field change

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

So I have some textbox on my form,and on the last textbox, I turn off the `enable` so instead of asking the user for the input, I want to make the value on the textbox calculate automatically when the user input on another textbox, so I set the default value like this :

```
=IIf(IsNull([jmlh]),0,[jmlh]*[harga]*IIf([diskon]>0,[diskon],1))
```

But the problem is the expression just work when the form loaded, it's still not when value in "[jmlh]" change. Is there any method or something to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your expression into `Default Value`, but into `Control Source` property.

Then it will always update itself when one of the used fields changes.

---

If it is a bound field (but why would you want a calculated field stored in the table?), you need to put that formula into a VBA function

```
Private Function UpdateCalcField()
     Me.calcField = IIf(IsNull([jmlh]),0,[jmlh]*[harga]*IIf([diskon]>0,[diskon],1))
End Function
```

and call that function from the `AfterUpdate` events of all involved fields.